# How to reassign taxonomies in Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal

I'm having to create new taxonomies for a client and they want nodes that are associated with these terms and taxonomies to be assigned to the new taxonomy, I have done this via MySQL with an update statement so that all nodes associated with a certain term are now associated with the new one e.g.

UPDATE taxonomy_copy SET tid = 316 WHERE tid = 152

Now when I do my `select *` query it shows all the nodes are associated with the new taxonomy but when I check the front end the node is still associated with the previous taxonomy. I've cleared cache and history and this still doesn't help.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a stab in the dark here...

As I [replied to 'Chris'](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41902/why-are-nodes-not-being-reassigned-to-new-term-when-termid-is-changed) who posted exactly the same question yesterday, it's likely that you're updating the `taxonomy_index` table (not `taxonomy_copy`, which doesn't exist in a standard Drupal installation), without taking into account how that data is actually stored against the node.

The `taxonomy_index` table is just an index table, the 'real' data is stored in the field tables (because taxonomy terms are related to entities via fields in Drupal 7). As such updating the `taxonomy_index` won't actually update the data you're looking for.

You really need to use the API functions to handle this sort of thing, but since you've already updated `taxonomy_index` your data is in an consistent state at the moment.

I'd recommend also manually updating the `field_data_field_name` and `field_revision_field_name` tables; if you do, the data you're expecting to see against the nodes will suddenly appear after a cache flush.

An example query:

```
UPDATE field_data_field_name SET field_name_tid = 316 WHERE field_name_tid = 152
```

The same must be run for `field_revision_field_name` as field data is stored in 2 places in Drupal 7.

Please bear in mind this is just a guess, it would be worth confirming that this is definitely the problem before running any more queries against the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we actually work for the same company and we didn;t think anyone had replied.

We just duplicated that table incase we messed it up. We will have ago at what you said and let you know know how we get on.

Thanks Robert